# Numbers made from digits 1-9 -- proving the exceptions?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, provability, automated-theorem-proving

*Inspired by [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.1479)*

---

## Introduction

In this paper, a sequential representation of a number is a formula that uses the digits 1-9 in order with the mathematical operations **+, -, ×, ÷, ^**, as well as brackets, and digit-to-digit concatenation.

For example, 100 can be represented as follows:
$$100 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 × 9$$
More complicated formulae look more like this:
$$11106 = (1 + 2^3)^4 + 567 × 8 + 9$$
$$1+i = (-1)^{(2+3+4)/(5+6+7)}-8+9$$

---

## Question

Curiously enough, a solution the number **10958** has not been found*, despite extensive searching and computing. It was even touched upon in a [numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ruC5A9EzzE).

> Can we prove certain numbers must or must not have a sequential representation?

**Cited as "still not available" in the paper*

---

### Related questions

*Note: don't strain yourself, they're not as important.*

> 1. What is the trivial minimum/maximum bounds with sequential representation?
> 2. Can we answer these questions with more simple rules? Such as removing concatenation or exponentiation. Or perhaps the rule of digit order?
> 3. Since there is a finite amount of combinations one can make with these digits and operations, how many combinations are there?
> 4. How many unique numbers have a sequential representation?

Comment: I looked $10958$ up in the OEIS. Just sixteen results, none of them seem relevant to your very interesting question.